# SQL Query to display the repeated value in column once and to get sum of the repeated codes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like follows -

| Person_number | One_amount | other_code | Other_amount | M_code | M_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 10 | SCK | 10 | COV | 2 |
| 12 | 10 | VAC | 2.5 | BRV | 5 |
| 12 | 10 | SCK | 3 | BRV | 6 |
| 12 | 10 | GHJ | 1 | LOA | 1 |
| 12 | 10 | GHJ | 3 | COV | 2 |
| 13 |  |  |  |  |  |

The output should be like -

| Person_number | One_amount | other_code | Other_amount | M_code | M_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 10 | SCK | 13 | BRV | 11 |
| 12 |  | VAC | 2.5 | LOA | 1 |
| 12 |  | GHJ | 4 | COV | 4 |

The `one_amount` column should have 1 value for the same `person_number`. `Other_amount` should have the sum for the same code for the same employee.
So it should be 10+3 for `SCK` value and 4 for `GHJ`. Same for M_CODE, The same codes, corresponding amount should be sum, BRV should be 11, COV 4

I am using the below query but I am not getting the expected result. How can I tweak the below query -

```sql
SELECT person_number,
       CASE
          WHEN one_amount = LAG(one_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number, other_code ORDER BY other_code) THEN
           NULL
          ELSE
           SUM(one_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number, other_code ORDER BY other_code END other_amount,CASE
         WHEN other_code = LAG(other_code) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number, other_code ORDER BY other_code) THEN
          NULL
         ELSE
          other_code
       END other_code,
       CASE
         WHEN m_amount = lag(m_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number, m_code ORDER BY m_code) THEN
          NULL
         ELSE
          SUM(m_code) over(PARTITION BY person_number, m_code ORDER BY m_code END m_amount, 
       CASE WHEN m_code = LAG(m_code) OVER (PARTITION BY person_number, m_code ORDER BY m_code) 
         THEN 
           NULL 
         ELSE m_code 
  FROM base_table
```

Comment: Please when asking questions give us CREATE TABLE and INSERT commands.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need a `CROSS JOIN` among grouped subqueries through matching by an analytic function such as `ROW_NUMBER()`

```sql
SELECT t1.person_number, CASE WHEN rn1=1 THEN one_amount END AS one_amount, 
       t1.other_code, other_code, other_amount, m_code, m_amount
  FROM (SELECT person_number, other_code, SUM(other_amount) AS other_amount,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_number ORDER BY 0) AS rn1,
               MAX(one_amount) AS one_amount
          FROM t
         GROUP BY person_number, other_code) t1
         ,
       (SELECT person_number, m_code, SUM(m_amount) AS m_amount,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_number ORDER BY 0) AS rn2
          FROM t
         GROUP BY person_number, m_code) t2
 WHERE rn2 = rn1  
   AND t2.person_number = t1.person_number
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d338785dd7a306f6b0dab05b1264c0db)</kbd>